# How to disable the initial values in a kendo mvc multiselect, so they wont be unselected?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-multiselect

I'm trying to have a kendo multiselect filled with some initial values which can't be removed later by the user.

I've tried to run through the DataBond event of multiselect widget and get each of the elements, but I couldn't accomplish what I'm trying. 
Maybe (or more probably) I'm doing something wrong.

Also, I've seen this to disable elements:

```
<span class="#: unselectableItem ? 'k-state-disabled': ''#">
     #: text #
</span>
```

But i'm not sure, how to implement it.

What I have so far:

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect().Name("msEquipoResponsable")
     .DataValueField("Id").DataTextField("Tipo")
     .DataSource(ds => ds.Read(r => r.Action("ObtenerPersonal","AuditoriaPlaneacionMemorandoEditor")))
     .Value(Model.EquipoResponsable.Split(','))
     .Events(ev => ev.DataBound("onBindingMS"))
  )
```

DataBound function:

```
function onBindingMS(event) 
   {
        var dataItems = event.sender._dataItems;
        $.each(dataItems, (ind, el) => {
            //Disabled logic should be here i guess...
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try preventing the [`deselect`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/multiselect/events/deselect) event to be completed using `e.preventDefault()` for those items which cannot be deselected.

```
deselect: function(e) {
    if (e.dataItem.unselectableItem)
    {
        // Call preventDefault() to prevent the deselection
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

In the snippet below, items `Item1` and `Item3` starts selected and cannot be deselected according to the `unselectableItem` property:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script></head>
<body>
</body>
  <select id="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
    <option selected>Item1</option>
    <option>Item2</option>
</select>
<script id="item-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
  <span class="#: unselectableItem ? 'k-state-disabled': ''#">
     #: text #
 </span>
</script>
<script>
$("#multiselect").kendoMultiSelect({
  dataSource: [{
    id: 1,
    text: "Item1",
    unselectableItem: true
  },{
    id: 2,
    text: "Item2",
    unselectableItem: false
  },{
    id: 3,
    text: "Item3",
    unselectableItem: true
  },{
    id: 4,
    text: "Item4",
    unselectableItem: false
  }],
  dataValueField: "id",
  itemTemplate: $("#item-template").html(),
  tagTemplate: $("#item-template").html(),
  deselect: function(e) {
    if (e.dataItem.unselectableItem)
    {
      // Call preventDefault() to prevent the deselection
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  },
  value: [1,3]
});
</script>
</html>
```

[Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/iriVoqAS)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
We use 2014 version which doesn't have the deselect event (sorry for not letting that clear in the question). So, i think i can't do it that way. Is there any way with the select or the change event that I can do so?